# Laravel Role HasMany relationship

Tags: laravel, class, model, roles

I have a `User Model` and a `Role Model` which are in many-to-many relation.
I have two roles: admin and manager. 
I also have an `Order Model`. Managers need to have many orders. Where do I state such relations? Do I have to state it in the User Class?
Do I need to create separate models for Admins and Managers?

Comment: Please see what Laratrust do. Maybe, it is what you need. https://laratrust.readthedocs.io/en/5.0/

Comment: Can try this https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managers & admins are a subset of your users, defined by their roles.

Therefore, we'll use scope to filter users who are managers by their roles.

**App\Scopes\ManagerUserScope.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class ManagerUserScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        //Assuming Your user has a relationship (has many) role
        $builder->whereHas('role', function($roleQuery) {
            //Assuming that in the role table, the manager role entry has ID 1
            $roleQuery->where('id','=',1);
        });
    }
}
```

Then, we extend the `User` model to create a manager model which has the above scope automatically applied.

**App\Models\Manager.php**

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Scopes\ManagerUserScope;

class Manager extends User {

    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new ManagerUserScope);
    }

    /**
    *  Relationship: Orders (Has many)
    */
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('orders');
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I hoped to find!

Answer (score 1):

Your many-to-many relationship between `User` and `Role` can be perfectly described with `belongsToMany` Eloquent relation methods both ways. Also since each `Order` must have responsible manager for it we also have one-to-many relation between `Manager` and `Order` which will be described with `hasMany`/`belongsTo` methods.

So, your `User` model will have:

```php
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}

public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
}
```

For your `Role` model:

```php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

And lastly your `Order` model:

```php
public function manager()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

There is no need to create a certain limitations (like "only users with role manager can have orders") on DB schema level, it's easier to implement in the code. So, for example, you might want to implement a method that will assign order to user and check his roles first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's what I actually did, yet I wasn't completely sure it is okay to make all user have orders while only managers could.

Comment: @Zlautumn also, check official documentation about [gates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#writing-gates). It's a preferred method when you need to implement some role based checks. In your case you can create a gate named "can-have-orders" and make it return true if passed User has manager role assigned. Then in your code you will be able to use nice and short checks using `Gate` facade or blade directives (like @can and so on).